# Change image in button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How to change an image in a button? In my case how to change `"@drawable/notConnected"`with another image? Is there any way to do this?

**Here is my xml**

```
<Button
    android:text="CONNECTION"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/notConnected"
    android:id="@+id/wifiButton" />
```

Comment: replace the image with same name..

Comment: I should change programmaticaly. And there is no method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose that you want to change programmatically. As you are using `drawableRight` attribute to set the image, you have to:

```
wifiButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.newImage, 0);
```

Hope it helps!